# How can I address an enumeration type defined in a module?

Tags: powershell-5.0, powershell-core

In one of our PowerShell modules we have defined an enumeration type:

`myModule.psm1`

```bsh
[Flags()]
enum MyEnum {
  Value1 = 1
  Value2 = 2
  Value3 = 4
}

Function Have-Some
(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
  [MyEnum]
  $enumValue
) {
}
```

Now, from a script I'd like to address this type to call the `Have-Some` function.

None of the below methods seems to work:

```bsh
Have-Some Value1,Value2
Have-Some "Value1,Value2"
Have-Some [MyEnum]Value1,Value2
Have-Some [MyEnum]"Value1,Value2"
Have-Some [MyEnum]Value1 + [MyEnum]Value2
Have-Some [MyEnum]Value1 -bor [MyEnum]Value2
```

I always get the same (or similar) error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'enumValue'. Cannot convert value "[MyEnum]::Value1" to type "MyEnum". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name [MyEnum]::Value1 to a valid 
enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
Value1, Value2, Value3"
```

What's the correct way to call the `Have-Some` function with two or more `MyEnum` flags?